# Color picker in widget appears twice when added via the Customizer

Tags: widgets, theme-customizer, color-picker

I've used this https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/25809/color-picker-widget.php as a reference to add a color picker to custom widget. Everything works great when this widget is added into the sidebar in Appearance -> Widgets, but when i add the widget via the Customizer, the color picker appear twice when the first instance does not response to click, only the second is clickable and works as it should.

After page is refreshed or after the Customizer is saved, the first non clickable color picker disappears and i can see only one, working color picker.

All suggested fixes have no affect on widget in Customizer.

See two images of two widget's situations:

**Widget Added:**

[image: Widget Added]

**Widget Updated:**

[image: Widget Updated]

Comment: Hi Vasili,  Need to see your code in order to help...

Comment: Hi rudtek, it's the whole code from this file https://core.trac.wordpress.org/attachment/ticket/25809/color-picker-widget.php